# Stack Overflow Careers - URL param verified=false?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs

I recently signed up for Stack Overflow Careers and was finishing up my profile. A few days later I looked at it and just happened to notice a parameter in the URL when I click "My Profile":

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/******?verified=False#
```

I followed the link "view & manage your profile" in the Careers homepage:

> [image]

Are there other verification steps? My e-mail is validated. Do they do other things to verify your account without you doing anything?

Comment: Can you clarify what URL you see this parameter on?

Comment: Edited to answer.

Comment: @Dean I've added a screenshot on the OP's behalf as well. :)

Comment: Got here via Google while searching for the answer to this exact question. Now @Jon-Chan has me curious!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, there are no further verification steps. The `?verified=False` parameter you're seeing is for an upcoming change we're pushing later this month to allow more people to get Careers profiles. It has no effect on the current profile and you don't need to do anything.

More to come in the next few weeks.

Comment: Is there any plan to make a better URL that can be included on resumes? ie. careers.....com/realname

Comment: You can actually do that already - go to your profile and go to your Profile Settings and you can create a custom URL

Comment: it is kind of mis-directing to the users saying "verified=false". Most of them are developers so they think something in our profile not verified. In short, bad UX.